# Is there a "repeat [function] until [property = true]" type of loop in MakeCode JS?

Tags: javascript, 2d-games, makecode

I'm making a game in Microsoft MakeCode Arcade for a school project, and I wanted to know if there was a "repeat [function] until [property = true]" type of loop like there is in Luau. I wanted to use this so that the game waits until my player sprite is at a certain coordinate to run some code. I figured out a way to do this in a different way, but I wanted to know just for future reference.

If anyone is wondering, this is what the alternative way I am using.

```
game.onUpdateInterval(100, function () {
    if (level == 1) {
        if (myPlayer.x == 950 && myPlayer.y == 140) {
            myPlayer.y = 100
            myPlayer.x = 10
            if (game.ask("Does " + level_1 + " + " + level1_2 + " = " + level1CorrectAns + "?")) {
                console.log("Level 1 Completed successfully")
                level += 1
                LevelChange()
            } else {
                game.over(false)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either `while` loop or `do...while` loop

For `while` loop, the following code will keep on running as long as the condition is true.

```
let x = 0

while (x < 3) {
  x++
}

console.log(x) // print 3
```

For `do...while` loop, the following code will keep on running as long as the condition is true. And this loop will run at least once.

```
let result = '';
let x = 0;

do {
  x = x + 1;
  result = result + x;
} while (x < 5);

console.log(result); // print "12345"
```

Coming back to your example, I believe you're running the loop every `100ms` (based on first argument of your `game.onUpdateInterval`.

You could easily do this by adding a `timer` function and wrap this loop in as an async function.

```
const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

async function updateInterval() {
  while () {
  // Your logic here
  await timer(100) // You can change the timeout to your desired ms
  }
}

updateInterval();
```

While I'm not 100% sure of the functionality of your current workaround, but this is my interpretation (Hope it works)

```
const timer = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function updateInterval() {
  let state = true; // This is just a condition if the loop should continue
  while (state) {
    if (level == 1) {
      if (myPlayer.x == 950 && myPlayer.y == 140) {
        myPlayer.y = 100;
        myPlayer.x = 10;
        if (
          game.ask(
            'Does ' +
              level_1 +
              ' + ' +
              level1_2 +
              ' = ' +
              level1CorrectAns +
              '?'
          )
        ) {
          console.log('Level 1 Completed successfully');
          level += 1;
          LevelChange();
          state = false; // Update the state to false, so it will exit the while loop
        } else {
          game.over(false);
        }
      }
    }
    await timer(100); // You can change the timeout to your desired ms
  }
}

updateInterval();
```

Comment: Nice, Thank you!